# Why are "conv.close()" or "conv.ask()" not displaying anything on slack?

Tags: aws-lambda, slack, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

So we are using actions-on-google v2 with aws-lambda and Dialogflow. Using the code provided in the github, we cannot seem to get the bot to answer on slack using the `ask` or `close` methods.

This is the code we are using to test:

```
const app = dialogflow({ debug: true });

app.intent("[intent id]", conv => {
    conv.close("test text");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions-on-google v2 library is only for usage with Actions on Google, not Slack.

Use [Dialogflow Fulfillment](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) library instead.

[Here](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/samples/quick-start/functions/index.js) is a quick start, you may need to make some changes for aws-lambda.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! The problem I have with this solution is the adaptation for AWS of the request/response parameters needed in the constructor seems a bit complicated, unless you have any kind of resources that would help me do that.

Comment: Hi, do you need to use AWS platform? I am sorry, but my knowledge about AWS is limited. Because the Dialogflow Fulfillment library is relatively new, I couldn't find any resources for using it with AWS. However, I found this [article](https://medium.com/@marcorei/developing-for-the-google-assistant-using-typescript-and-amazon-web-services-e7c81df9a436), it is about AoG, but maybe some part can help you out? If not, could you please give me more information about the problem?